# Why is $\Im((2 - i) z - 5 i)=2 \Im(z) - \Re(z) - 5$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Why is $\Im((2 - i) z - 5 i)=2 \Im(z) - \Re(z) - 5$?

What happens with the real parts in $\Im(\cdot )$?

Comment: Set $z=x+iy$ and just compute the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

Lert $z=x+iy$ then $$(2-i)(x+iy)-5i=2x+y+i(2y-x-5)$$